# numpy.allclose and multiprecision with mpmath

Tags: python, numpy, arbitrary-precision, mpmath

In my python code, I regularly verify some calculations using `numpy.allclose`. On the other hand, apart from these checks the implementation is able to deal with multiprecision (`mpmath.mpc`) numbers. If I want to run my verification code for the `mpmath` numbers, I get something like

```
>>> check(H)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "module.py", line 19, in check_H
  assert(numpy.allclose(H, I, rtol=rtol, atol=atol))
File "/home/gereon/python/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 2025, in allclose
  xinf = isinf(x)
TypeError: ufunc 'isinf' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could
not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

What is the best way to check if two multiprecision arrays are sufficiently equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked through the code (`allclose` in numeric.py). It depends on the `isinf` function, which is apparently not implemented for mpmath.

The function is simple enough though. It boils down to:

```
def allclose(x, y, rtol=1.e-5, atol=1.e-8):
    return all(less_equal(abs(x-y), atol + rtol * abs(y)))
```

You may have to replace `rtol` and `atol` with mpmath equivalents instead of floats.